# ¿Cómo utilizar la función CONCATENAR con IMPORTRANGE en google hoja de cálculo?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

**Escenario:**

Tengo dos documentos de hojas de cálculo de google drive:

- [Libro1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ/edit), con una hoja llamada "Dia1"
- [Libro2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hRemDihjX-fOOnYPoKFK7Zo3TTVJlZ7W7nzaIErRFYo/edit), con una hoja llamada "Consolidado"

Utilizo la función IMPORTRANGE en el Libro2 para traer el valor de la celda A1 de la hoja Dia1 del Libro1 sin problema alguno.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ";"Dia1!A1")
```

Rta: 150

ahora deseo construir la función IMPORTRANGE como una concatenación con el fin de hacerla parametrizable dentro de la misma hoja.

F1="Dia1" //En la celda F1 se ubica el valor a concatenar;

Intento:

```
=CONCATENAR("=IMPORTRANGE(""1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ"";""";F1;"!A1"")")
```

Aunque la concatenación es correcta, me devuelve el valor `=IMPORTRANGE("1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ";"Dia1!A1")` cómo un string.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pregunta:**

¿Cómo indicar que me ejecute el string concatenado para que me de el resltado deseado (150)?

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido publicada también en [so]. Véase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439690/how-to-use-the-function-concatenate-with-importrange-in-google-spreadsheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Formula

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ";CONCATENATE(F1;"!A1"))
```

## Explicación

1. Agregar una fórmula
   Para agregar una fórmula, se escribe el símbolo igual `=` al inicio de la fórmula. Esto sólo se hace una y sólo una vez por celda.
2. Anidar funciones
   A colocar una función como argumento de otra función se le llama anidar funciones.
3. Argumentos

En este caso, lo que se desea es concatenar el valor de una celda con un texto para obtener el argumento de la cadena de texto de la referencia, así que CONCATENATE debe usarse anidada dentro de IMPORTRANGE y no al revés.

Comment: También se puede concatenar utilizando el operador & http://stackoverflow.com/a/40440282/4564845... , he creado una sala de chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48075/google-hoja-de-calculo, te invito para charlar del tema...

Comment: Así es, también se puede usar `&`. En cuanto al chat, ya me uní :)